# Dr Java error on code

Tags: java, initialization, local-variables

It is saying that my local variable `newaccbalance` may not have been initialized. I know I declared it as a double. Help please

```
 import java.util.*;

public class Pg244Problem12 {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 

   int accnum, minbalance, currentbalance;
   int acctype;
   double newaccbalance;

   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);



   System.out.println("Enter the customer's account number:");
   accnum = console.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter the customer's account type by using the number 1 for Checking or 2 for Savings:");
   acctype = console.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter the minimum balance the customer's account can have:");
   minbalance = console.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter the current balance of the customer's account:");
   currentbalance = console.nextInt();



   // Checkings
    if(acctype == 1 && currentbalance >= (minbalance+5000)){
     newaccbalance = ((currentbalance*.05)*(1/12));
   }
    if (acctype == 1 && currentbalance >= minbalance && currentbalance <  (minbalance+5000)){
     newaccbalance = ((currentbalance*.03)*(1/12)); 
    }
    if (acctype == 1 && currentbalance < minbalance){
     newaccbalance = (currentbalance-25);
  }

   // Savings
    if (acctype == 2 && currentbalance >= minbalance){
      newaccbalance = ((currentbalance*.04)*(1/12));
    }
    if (acctype == 2 && currentbalance < minbalance){
      newaccbalance = (currentbalance - 10);
    }



    System.out.println("The account number is: "+ accnum);
    System.out.println("The account type is: "+ acctype);
    System.out.println("The current balance is: "+ currentbalance);
    System.out.println("The new account balance is: "+ newaccbalance);

  }
}
```

Comment: The code is not readable. Please edit :)

Comment: @CoderTian I just did! You can also submit an edit proposal for questions which needs to be improved.

Comment: this is my first time using this site im not very good at it

Comment: **declaring** and **initializing** is not the same thing.

Comment: how would i go about initializing it?

Comment: i edited it. is that any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, declaring and initializing is not the same thing.

`double newaccbalance;` declares the variable.

`newaccbalance = 42;` is **initializing** the variable.

The problem in your code is that the compiler can not guarantee that any of your if-statements will be true, therefore it is possible for `newaccbalance` to be left uninitialized.

I suggest two things:

First of all, initialize the variable to a default value, `double newaccbalance = 0;` will both declare and initialize the variable.

Secondly, change the structure of your if-statements and also use if-else-if, something like this:

```
if (acctype == 1) {
    // For these if statements, acctype is 1 so we don't need to check that again
    if(currentbalance >= (minbalance+5000)){
        newaccbalance = ((currentbalance*.05)*(1/12));
    }
    else if (currentbalance >= minbalance) {
        //  && currentbalance <  (minbalance+5000) will be true because the above if-statement is **not** true
        newaccbalance = ((currentbalance*.03)*(1/12)); 
    }
    else { 
        // if (acctype == 1 && currentbalance < minbalance) would always be true here
        newaccbalance = (currentbalance-25);
    }
}
else if (acctype == 2){
     // Savings
     if (currentbalance >= minbalance) {
          newaccbalance = ((currentbalance*.04)*(1/12));
     }
     else { // currentbalance < minbalance) is always true here
          newaccbalance = (currentbalance - 10);
     }
}
else {
     // acctype is neither 1 or 2, what should we do now? RuntimeError, Catastrophic failure, the monsters are coming! We're screwed!
}
```

Comment: Give your variable some default value when you declare it.

Comment: Either have `else` parts where this variable is assigned as well, or have it initialized during the declaration. See the above answers.

Comment: okay so i did what you said but its still not running that variable through the if statements. it just simply prints out 0

Comment: i have done that also and it still says it has not been initialized. im not sure how to get the variable to go through the if statements and print out what its new value is

Comment: @user2874840 See my updated answer. If the "variable is not running through the if-statements" it might be because acc-type is neither 1 or 2.

Comment: well i input the acctype so it was one or the other

Answer (score 1):

You are *declaring* your variable. You need to **initialize** your variable.

Declaring is where you create the variable:

```
double newaccbalance;
```

Initializing is where you assign a variable a value:

```
newaccbalance = 0;
```

So what you need to do is:

```
double newaccbalance = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

All your assignments are wrapped in `if` control structures.  If **none** of the conditions is evaluated to `true`, the variable will remain unassigned. As a `local` variable it does not get a default value either.

That is why the message says that it ***may*** be not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It is not initialized.  When you declare it try double newaccbalance = 0.0;

I think the problem is newaccbalance is only set conditionally (in the if statements) so it can never be guaranteed to be set to a value.

Initializing and declaring are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're getting an error, but a warning.
Regardless, Java is correct.
Your variable newaccbalance may not have been initialized.

You've declared it a double, but you only assign it a value inside if statements.
Java does not know whether those if statements cover all possible cases and therefore warns you what `newaccbalance` may in fact be unassigned.

Note that Java does not assign a zero value to undefined variables.
You have to do that yourself.

Change the top declaration to :

```
double newaccbalance = 0;  //Or whatever default value you want.
```

Either that or add an extra `else` behind the last one like so:

```
else if (acctype == 2 && currentbalance < minbalance){
  newaccbalance = (currentbalance - 10);
}
else { newaccbalance = 0; }
```

This will ensure to the compilers satisfaction the newaccbalance has a defined value, rather than a random one.
You should always ensure that this is the case and kuddo's for heeding the warning and taking action.
Undefined variables can be a source of very hard to track down bugs, because often the value turns out some reasonable value except in 1% of cases. Because every run of the code is different, it can be difficult to reproduce the bug, let alone diagnose it.

This is why Java is insistent.

Comment: i did that but it still doesnt run that variable through the if statements and return a new value it just says it is zero still